# Does $L^1$ convergence of vector-valued functions in each coordinate imply $L^1$ convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\mathscr{M},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space, so recall that we consider a function $f:X\to H$ to be measurable if $\langle f,\varphi\rangle:X\to\Bbb C$ is measurable for all $\varphi\in H$ (which implies measurability of $\lvert f\rvert$), and for measurable $f:X\to H$, we define $$\lVert f\rVert_{L^p(X,H)}=\lVert\lvert f\rvert\rVert_{L^p(X)}$$ and define $L^P(X,H)$ to be those measurable $f:X\to H$ with finite norm.

I can now introduce the setup: Let $f_n\in L^1(X,H)$ for all $n$, such that $$\langle f_n,\varphi\rangle\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$ in $L^1(X)$ for all $\varphi\in H$. Then is it true that $f_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ in $L^1(X,H)$?

In finite dimension, this seems easy to prove, and I presume that in the countable case, we need to use some complete orthonormal system $(\varphi_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, but I don't quite see how to do this.

Comment: If $f_n \in L^1(X,H)$ and $\phi \in H$, then what does $(f_n,\phi)$ mean? Consider $X = H = R$. Then we would have $f_n \in L^1(R)$. $\phi$ is now a real and $f_n$ an element in a sequence of functions of the reals!

Comment: $(f_n,\varphi)$ turns a vector valued function into a complex valued function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Let $(e_n)$ be an ON basis for $H$. 
Let $X$ be ${\mathbb N}$ with the counting measure, and let $f_n (m)=e_n{\bf 1}_n(m)$. Then $\|f_n\|_1 =1$, so the sequence does not converge to zero in $L^1$. However, for $\varphi \in H$, 
$(f_n,\varphi) (m) = (e_n ,\varphi){\bf 1}_n (m)\Rightarrow \|(f_n,\varphi)\|_1 = (e_n , \varphi) \to 0$ as  $n\to\infty$.

[Edit] Observe that in the last example one can get $f_n (m)= e_n{\bf 1}_{\{1\}}(m)$. Then $|f_n|\le {\bf 1}_{\{1\}}\in L^1(X)$ (this did not hold for the first example).  Of course, $\|f_n\|_1=1$ for all $n$, so sequence does not converge to $0$ in $L^1$. However, for every $\varphi \in H$,  $(f_n,\varphi)(m) = {\bf 1}_{\{1\}}(m) (e_n ,\varphi) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ (even uniformly in $m$ because identically zero for all $m>1$).

Comment: What happens if we place the constraint that there exists some nonnegative $g\in L^1(X)$ such that $\lvert f_n\rvert\le g$ almost everywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure. Check Dunford-Pettis theorem.

Comment: Actually, I added a simpler example that shows that the answer  remains negative even under the added condition.